# Switched capacitor sample and hold circuit as as mixer

Tags: rf, sampling, mixer, harmonics, sample-and-hold

I am trying to find out how important the "hold " level in a sample and hold down-conversion mixer is.
If the level is decreased, will it lead to any loss?

Out of these three subfigures, which one is correct?

Please justify.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's just the math behind that kind of mixer.

To understand that, you should look at the very common example of why a "zero-order hold" is *not* an appropriate reconstruction filter for DACs. Exactly the same math applies here:

You're producing images of the sampled signal, at regular (sample-interval-spaced) frequency distances. Some of these end up at a lower frequency. With appropriate low-pass filtering, you can build a downconversion mixer from this.

Note that this is, at least as far as I know, a bit of an unusual solution to the mixing problem. I'm not a high-speed semiconductor person, but as far as I can tell from radio applications, up to several GHz, you get better results with actual doubly-balanced mixers, even in MOS technologies; then comes a region where CMOS chopping mixers still work.

I'm sure there's a special application field (maybe together with SAR ADCs?) or CMOS technology where this is advantageous.

Generally, it does have some fundamental problems, as you note:

> If the level gets decrease, will it lead to any loss?

yes, means mixing with a decreasing, nonlinear envelope. You get intermodulation *within* the signal's bandwidth, which is the opposite of what you want.

> Out of these three subfigures, which one is correct?

"Correct" for what? This question is inanswerable without knowing what "correct" means. (And I guess knowing that is your homework.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, I would like to find out the difference between in case of an RZ mixer(with only track and zero hold ) and a sampling mixer(with sample and hold output), in terms of the output spectrum. Since the former is having  only a zero hold level (true since the load is a resistor, which only tracks the input), does not have the same translated images as  the later

Comment: short answer (I'm on my way to bed and probably won't have time to look at this tomorrow):  as said, look at the DAC reconstruction filter. If you use a "hold" you're pulse-shaping (i.e. convolving) with rectangles, and that leads to the spectrum of a rectangular wave multiplied with the signal spectrum.